# PHP CURL BadRequest

Tags: php, json, curl

I am attempting to send a print job through PrintNode. I keep getting met with the same error message:

code: BadRequest
message: Incorrect request body: (request body).content must be present

I am relatively new to CURL, here is my code:

```
     $pdf_path = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .  'pdfs/Order8221.pdf';
    
    
    $url = 'https://api.printnode.com/printjobs';
    $data_array = array(

            'printerId' => 70029019,
            'title' =>  'My test print',
            'contentType' => 'pdf_uri',
            'content' => $pdf_path,
            'source' => 'api doc'

    );

    $data = json_encode($data_array);
    echo'<br/>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '<br/>';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'API KEY*******' . ":" . '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if the file exists ?

Comment: Yes. The files exists and can be found by following the generated URL

Comment: I am not sure but I think you must supply CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS as a URL-encoded query string so you should try `http_build_query($data_array)` or `http_build_query($data_array, '', '&');`

Comment: oh wow! thank you! that worked perfectly! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
$data = json_encode($data_array);
```

with :

```
$data = http_build_query($data_array);
```

and it worked.